# dar foco em input carregado via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

0
votar contra
favorita

Tenho uma página em que estou dando refresh com ajax apenas na div conteúdo. Ela está configurada assim:

div1: Carrego 2 selects onde o usuário escolherá estes 2 dados (classe e bimestre)

div 2: Carrego o menu da aplicação (menu.php) fim da div 2

div id="conteudo": Carrego a página que lê os 2 selects e carrega a página php correspondente, de acordo com o item escolhido no menu na div2 fim da div id="conteudo"

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Quando clico num determinado item do menu (que está na div2) carrega uma página dentro da div conteudo que contem vários inputs criados dinamicamente. Cada um destes inputs tem um id. Preciso, automaticamente, dar foco e sair destes inputs para rodar uma função javascript.
Não estou conseguindo fazer isso.
Estou testando apenas com o input com id 01001 e não funciona de forma alguma.
Vou postar aqui o que já tentei para ver se alguém consegue descobrir o que estou fazendo de errado.

```js
function AlteraConteudo()
{
var ajax = AjaxF(); 
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(ajax.readyState == 4)
 {
  document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
   alert("fora");    
        $("input.bordanotastarjeta").maskMoney({showSymbol:false, decimal:".", thousands:".", precision:1,defaultZero:true, allowZero:true});
 
     window.setTimeout(function ()
     {
   alert("dentro");
   document.getElementById('01002').focus();
      document.getElementById('01002').blur();        
     }, 0);   
  //$('#notas').css('background', 'black');   
  //document.getElementById('01001').focus();
  //document.getElementById('01001').blur(); 
  //$('#01001').focus();
  //$('#01001').blur();   
 }
};
// Variável com os dados que serão enviados ao PHP
var dados = "classe="+document.getElementById('classes').value+"&bimestre="+document.getElementById('bimestre').value+"&ano="+document.getElementById('ano').value+"&tipo="+document.getElementById('tipo').value;
var pagina = document.getElementById('pagina').value;
ajax.open("GET", pagina + dados, false);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
ajax.send();
}
```

Até a linha do maskmoney funciona.
O que está abaixo não funciona.
Obrigada

Código que funcionou:

```js
function AlteraConteudo()
{
var ajax = AjaxF(); 
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(ajax.readyState == 4)
 {
  document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
   alert("fora2"); 
   //document.getElementById(01002).focus(); 
     window.setTimeout(function ()
     {
     alert("dentro");
     document.getElementById('01002').focus();
      document.getElementById('01002').blur();        
     }, 0);     
        $("input.bordanotastarjeta").maskMoney({showSymbol:false, decimal:".", thousands:".", precision:1,defaultZero:true, allowZero:true});

      //document.getElementById(01002).blur();    
 
 
  //$('#notas').css('background', 'black');   
  //document.getElementById('01001').focus();
  //document.getElementById('01001').blur(); 
  //$('#01001').focus();
  //$('#01001').blur();   
 }
};
// Variável com os dados que serão enviados ao PHP
var dados = "classe="+document.getElementById('classes').value+"&bimestre="+document.getElementById('bimestre').value+"&ano="+document.getElementById('ano').value+"&tipo="+document.getElementById('tipo').value;
var pagina = document.getElementById('pagina').value;
ajax.open("GET", pagina + dados, false);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
ajax.send();
}
```

Mais um teste que fiz: colocando acima do maskmoney nem precisou do setTimeout. Ele faz o focus e o blur sem ele (o setTimeOut).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu tive um problema parecido mas a minha solução acredito que não serve para você , então dei uma olhada e achei no SOen [link de referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096436/document-getelementbyidid-focus-is-not-working-for-firefox-or-chrome) a seguinte solução :

Colocar um `setTimeout`

```
//... seu codigo
   $("input.bordanotastarjeta").maskMoney({showSymbol:false, decimal:".", thousands:".", precision:1,defaultZero:true, allowZero:true});    
   setTimeout(function ()
       {
        alert("dentro");
        document.getElementById('01002').focus();
        //document.getElementById('01002').blur();                     
       }, 0);
//... seu codigo
```

Essa resposta serviu para o usuário, veja se ela te serve também.

Esse erro/problema acontece muitas vezes porque ele tenta executar o `.focus()` antes mesmo do elemento ser renderizado, por isso o do timer

Comment: Bom dia, tudo bem?
Não resolveu...
Até coloquei alerts dentro do código para testar o funcionamento.
O alert "dentro" não abre.
Será que desta forma, window.setTimeout funciona dentro do ajax?

Comment: Editei a pergunta colocando o código como está agora, com os alerts que inclui para teste.
Obrigada

Comment: @ReginaLúciaTorresChaves eu editei, minha resposta, não sei pq mas se vc deixar os comando `.focus` e `blur` funcionando ao mesmo tempo n acontece nada.

Comment: Acho que o que estava fazendo não funcionar era o maskmoney.Coloquei a função que vc sugeriu acima do maskmoney e começou a funcionar (tanto o focus como o blur)
Obrigada pela ajuda